# Stop .filter() on first match in Django with Postgres

Tags: django

Is there a way to stop querying the remaining records in the database after the query returns a match.

For instance if I do this:

```
Profile.objects.filter(first_name='Dwight')
```

I want it to stop running the query for all the Profiles as soon as it finds a `Profile` with the `first_name` of **Dwight**.

Comment: `Profile.objects.filter(first_name='Dwight').first()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [.objects.first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#first) will return the first occurence by default sort order (which might be primary key, if you haven't specified a setting in your model.  Note this is not returned as a queryset - it is always a single entry.

Comment: Yes, this will return the first one, but it has already scanned through all the records in the database.